# What if I ask for death since I fear sinning

Tags: halal-haram, sin, dua, death, jahannam

Is it permissible in this case? I have been looking around but can't find an asnwer

Answer (score 0):

***Asking for death to Allah or anyone else is generally considered to be a serious sin.** This is because Muslims view life as a precious gift from Allah and asking for death may be seen as a rejection of this gift. Additionally, suicide is strictly prohibited in Islam, as taking one's own life goes against the belief that life is sacred and that Allah is the only one who has the right to determine the length of a person's life.*